# How to dynamically calculate session timeout?

Tags: java, ajax, session, servlets, timeout

Hi I am trying to calculate from my `/logout` servlet the session timeout. I have defined a certain amount of time before timeout as `timeout`

My doPost method is here:

```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;

   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
   import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
   import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.Status;

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    long timePassed = 0;
    long timeout = 60;

    timePassed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - request.getSession().getLastAccessedTime())/1000;
    System.out.println(timePassed);

    response.setStatus(Status.OK.getStatusCode());
    response.getWriter().write("[{\"timePassed\": \""+ timePassed + "\", \"limit\": \""+ timeout + "\"}]");
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); 

    if(timePassed >= timeout){
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

I hit this method every second with an ajax call. The ajax call works fine. GUI works fine because I am getting the data in the front end. BUT `timePassed` stays at 0. How do I get it to calculate the time that the user has spent idle?

Comment: Hitting the server with Ajax counts as a session access. So by doing that, you're keeping the session from expiring.

Comment: @developerwjk Yes I realized that I am still stuck on how to do it another way.

Comment: When you say idle, what do you mean?  There is a session create time but the difference there would just be the age since the session was created, not "idle".

Comment: Lol, how do you declared private static long timeout = 60; in non-static method. private static???

Comment: @RohitGaikwad sorry that was a typo

Comment: @stdunbar by idle I mean the time since the last action was taken by the user

Comment: Ok, looks fine now. please provide import statements for Status and MediaType.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad updated

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use javascript to detect clicks or mouse movements?

jQuery or native Javascript can accomplish what you need...

[Edit]

If certains calls to the backend release the idle time, you can monitor those with Javascript :-)

Comment: Yes I figured that out. But what I'm trying to do is hold the time left in the back end. So that I can maintain a session across multiple tabs and keep them in sync.

Comment: I would store it in a store (database, file, session object in java [if that exists]) and when the user hits the server again, retrieve the last stored date time. Do you use authentication? Example of storage {Key: UserX, Value: 20160916 16:27} in database. If the user hits, then retrieve for that user it's last active time...

If you need to sync data between client and server, use SignalR or other lib where the server can communicate with client using websockets, polling,...

Answer (score 1):

You are getting timePassed stays as 0 because, I guess you are directly calling the servlet.

Do one thing, Add some debug points at the below code and restart your server in debug mode. when the debugger reaches the debug point wait for 5-6 seconds and suspend the debugging by pressing press F8. you will definitely get some value for timePassed other than 0.

```
timePassed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - request.getSession().getLastAccessedTime())/1000;
System.out.println(timePassed);
```

One more trick, instead of debug. when you get the timePassed value as zero then wait for few seconds and refresh the page(resubmit the form). you will get the output as below:

[image: Session TimeOut]

This is because, when you first redirect to the servlet, the session time lapsed is 0, Since the session is just started. and when a new request is made in same session the time lapsed will increase.

Hope this helps you.